# Find out the least insecure mutual cipher algorithm

Tags: ssh, cipher-selection

I have set the cipher algorithms for ssh on my server to just chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com, aes256-gcm@openssh.com and aes128-gcm@openssh.com

Now my IntelliJ fails with this error:

> failed: unable to reach a settlement: [aes128-cbc, aes128-ctr, aes192-cbc, aes192-ctr, aes256-cbc, aes256-ctr, blowfish-cbc, blowfish-ctr, cast128-cbc, cast128-ctr, idea-cbc, idea-ctr, serpent128-cbc, serpent128-ctr, serpent192-cbc, serpent192-ctr, serpent256-cbc, serpent256-ctr, 3des-cbc, 3des-ctr, twofish128-cbc, twofish128-ctr, twofish192-cbc, twofish192-ctr, twofish256-cbc, twofish256-ctr, twofish-cbc, arcfour, arcfour128, arcfour256] and [chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com, aes256-gcm@openssh.com, aes128-gcm@openssh.com]

So I will have to enable one of the ciphers that IntelliJ uses, but how do I find out which of this list is the least insecure?

```
aes128-cbc, aes128-ctr, aes192-cbc, aes192-ctr, aes256-cbc, aes256-ctr, blowfish-cbc, blowfish-ctr, cast128-cbc, cast128-ctr, idea-cbc, idea-ctr, serpent128-cbc, serpent128-ctr, serpent192-cbc, serpent192-ctr, serpent256-cbc, serpent256-ctr, 3des-cbc, 3des-ctr, twofish128-cbc, twofish128-ctr, twofish192-cbc, twofish192-ctr, twofish256-cbc, twofish256-ctr, twofish-cbc, arcfour, arcfour128, arcfour256
```

---

Update: I guess, that would be `aes256-ctr`, but that is just a guess

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `aes256-ctr` is the right cipher to choose from those available to you.

Since it's not an AEAD, you need to choose a [MAC](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#MACs). You should choose an '-etm' one if you can, and among those I'd choose the fastest.

Also make sure you have a strong [key exchange](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#KexAlgorithms) (in descending order of preference: curve25519, ecdh-sha2-nistp256, diffie-hellman-group18/16/14, not something with sha1) and strong [host key](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#HostKeyAlgorithms) (in descending order of preference: ed25519, ecdsa with nistp256, RSA, nothing with sha1 or DSS).

If IntelliJ doesn't support a secure ssh configuration, complain to JetBrains.